# Change background position with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, background-position

I'd like to change the background position of a CSS-class while hovering a li-element.

HTML:

```
<div id="carousel">
    <ul id="submenu">
        <li>Apple</li>
        <li>Orange</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#carousel { 
    float: left;
    width: 960px;
    height: 360px;
    background: url(../images/carousel.png);
}
```

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submenu li').hover(function(){
        $('#carousel').css('background-position', '10px 10px');
    }, function(){
        $('#carousel').css('background-position', '');
    });
});
```

Comment: What is a valid value of `newValue`?  Is it a string?  What format is it in?

Comment: He is changing the 'css property backgroundPosition', more details here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background-position.asp

Comment: @Neil Updated Jakub's URL for w3schools background-position: [http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp). That explains what valid values of newValue could be.

Comment: Typically it's a string like this: `5px 10px` where the first value is **left** offset then the second is **top** offset. `%`, `em` etc are all fine as well as `px`. Don't forget that since it *pushes* the image in the container left and down, you want negative values unless you want the image to wrap around to the other side.

Answer (score 27):

You guys are complicating things. You can simple do this from CSS.

```
#carousel li { background-position:0px 0px; }
#carousel li:hover { background-position:100px 0px; }
```

Comment: @meo I am so tempted to say "Who cares?" but Argh. IE6.

Comment: IE6 is finally dead, even MS don't care about it

Comment: Everyone knows that IE6 is satan incarnate.  Anyone still using IE6 is either a companion to evil or a government employee.

Answer (score 5):

rebellion's answer above won't actually work, because to CSS, 'background-position' is actually shorthand for 'background-position-x' and 'background-position-y' so the correct version of his code would be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submenu li').hover(function(){
        $('#carousel').css('background-position-x', newValueX);
        $('#carousel').css('background-position-y', newValue);
    }, function(){
        $('#carousel').css('background-position-x', oldValueX);
        $('#carousel').css('background-position-y', oldValueY);
    });
});
```

It took about 4 hours of banging my head against it to come to that aggravating realization.

Comment: That works in some browsers, but not Firefox: [background-position-x is not standard css and is not supoprted in all browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511104/jquery-background-position-x-issue) - e.g. Firefox just ignores it even in jQuery v2, [see this demo](http://jsbin.com/ivupuj/2/edit)

Comment: [Here's something similar that does adjust either x or y cross browser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18515087/568458)

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#submenu li').hover(function(){
    $('#carousel').css('backgroundPosition', newValue);
});
```

Comment: Actually incomplete. Doesn't reset backgroundPostion when hovering stops. As it doesn't do that, also doesn't consider that there already might be meaningful value set for backgroundPosition which needs to be restored

Comment: Well thats all he asked for Jitter.

Comment: No. Reread question: "while hovering a li-element." Which to me implies "I want it reset when hovering stops"

Comment: No it doesn't jitter. If it said "while hovering a li-element. Then I want it reset when hovering stops" Then it would imply what you meant.

Sorry to be so petty, however that comment you left months ago really pissed me off.

Answer (score 2):

Sets new value for `backgroundPosition` on the `carousel` div when a li in the `submenu` div is hovered. Removes the `backgroundPosition` when hovering ends and resets `backgroundPosition` to old value.

```
$('#submenu li').hover(function() {
    if ($('#carousel').data('oldbackgroundPosition')==undefined) {
        $('#carousel').data('oldbackgroundPosition', $('#carousel').css('backgroundPosition'));
    }
    $('#carousel').css('backgroundPosition', [enternewvaluehere]);
},
function() {
    var reset = '';
    if ($('#carousel').data('oldbackgroundPosition') != undefined) {
        reset = $('#carousel').data('oldbackgroundPosition');
        $('#carousel').removeData('oldbackgroundPosition');
    }
    $('#carousel').css('backgroundPosition', reset);
});
```