# jquery background-position-x issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to do background-position-x in Jquery ?

```
console.log($('.element').css('background-position-x'));
```

Outputs `(an empty string)`

```
console.log($('.element').css('background-position'));
```

Outputs `0px 0px`

What I want to do is:

```
$(this).css('background-position-x', '-162px');
```

How to make it work ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You want to get the value or set the value for it?

Comment: Set a value, but if I can't get it it's hard to set, if I try to set it it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think `background-position-x` is a standard and hence may be its not supported by the browser you are using to test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`background-position-x` is not standard css and is not supoprted in all browsers. Take a look at solution at [Background Position animation in jQuery not working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378696/background-position-animation-in-jquery-not-working-in-firefox).

Comment: Ok, I'm on firefox, that explains why. Thank you, Do you have an idea how to do it ?

Comment: Just copy/paste the script on that solution and use it like you would normally do.

Comment: Ok thank you very much, but I'm going to do something a bit lighter.

Answer (score 9):

Basically you get and set `.css('backgroundPosition')`, which is a string with a space seperating x and y, for example `12px 14px`.

*Tested in Firefox, Chrome/Safari, Opera, IE7, IE8:*

---

### Get it

If you want only `background-position-x` from jQuery:

```
var bpx = $('elem').css('backgroundPosition').split(' ')[0];
```

---

If you want only `background-position-y` from jQuery:

```
 var bpy = $('elem').css('backgroundPosition').split(' ')[1];
```

---

If you want both `background-position-x` and `background-position-y` from jQuery:

```
var bp = $('elem').css('backgroundPosition').split(' ');
var bpx = bp[0], bpy = bp[1];
```

### Set it

*(if you need animation, see [Background Position animation in jQuery not working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378696/background-position-animation-in-jquery-not-working-in-firefox))*

To set `background-position-x` only without changing `background-position-y`:

```
var bpy = $('elem').css('backgroundPosition').split(' ')[1];
$('elem').css('backgroundPosition', '-192px ' + bpy);
```

---

To change or increment `background-position-x` only, based on its old value - for example, increase `background-position-x` by 5px:

*(this simple example assumes it's a pixel value, and not something else like a percentage)*

```
var bp = $('elem').css('backgroundPosition').split(' ');
var newBpx = (parseFloat(bp[0]) + 5) + 'px', bpy = bp[1];
$('elem').css('backgroundPosition', newBpx + ' ' + bpy );
```

Answer (score 0):

The output of

```
$('elem').css('backgroundPosition');
```

or more specifically

```
console($('elem').css('backgroundPosition');
```

sent to the console will be something like

```
elem.backgroundPosition 50% 0%
```

Where both the x- and y-values are assigned.
To assign the new values in Firefox, you would have to use something like

```
$('elem').css('backgroundPosition','50% 50%');
```

More likely, if you need to set a pixel dimension then you might have something that looks like

```
$('elem').css('backgroundPosition','50% -100px');
```

Which would shift your background image up (negative y-direction) one-hundred pixels.