# Setting background-position with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some `span` tag with let's say `#span` id that has the property `background: url(some image) -22px top no-repeat`, which displays some image as a background.

If it has the property `background: url(some image) -22px top no-repeat`, another image is displayed. The problem is that if I specify `('#span').attr('background-position','0px top')` nothing happens, the other image is not displayed. Could someone explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
$('#span').css('background-position','0px top');
```

> .css() ->  Get the value of style properties for the first element in the set of matched elements.

Comment: i think you can find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776950/change-background-position-with-jquery

Comment: @user1611830 Welcome. Never mind you learned a new thing .Be happy :)