# Set background position Javascript

Tags: javascript, background

So Im building a game and have a js script which loads a background image for each level only problem is I want the background to be in a certain position. How would I achieve this within the script?

My code is as follows:

```
var levels = {
    level1: {
                level: [[["0","1","0","1"],["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"]],[["0","0","1","1"],["0","1","1","0"],["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"]],[["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","1","1"],["1","1","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"]],[["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","1","1"],["1","0","1","0"],["1","0","1","0"],["1","1","0","0"]]],
                backgroundURL : "http://google.co.uk/level1.jpg" 
            },
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the css attibute background-position, as described in [another stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776950/change-background-position-with-jquery).

Provided you use jQuery, you could do

```
$('#canvas').css('background-position', '10px 10px');
```

where

```
<div id="canvas">
```

is the relevant HTML element.

Comment: I'd rather flag it as a duplicate, but apparently I'm lacking reputation for that.